# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable error while using python google search

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, http-error

I'm using python google search to get the top 3 links for a query.
The following is the code. My list contains 1000 queries and I'm trying to save them into a dictionary with the query as the key and URLs as the value.

```
from google import search
for each in list:
    time.sleep(1)
    for URL in search(each,stop=3,num=3):
        print URL
```

When I try to execute this, I get the error:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Should I use requests or any other libraries to eliminate this error?

Comment: Google hates bots. I think scraping is against their TOS.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: There used to be an ajax api but not anymore. You can signup to `developers.google.com` and use their api ( i think there is a small fee ). Or you can use bing, dogpile, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will try using bing.